# В слайдере в цикле указать на одном из слайдов класс active PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Есть слайдер, он спокойно работал на странице пока я до него не добрался , нужно сделать цикл foreach , что бы слайдер заполнялся элементами из БД, простая задача, но слайдер работает так, что первый элемент должен быть с классом active, я сломал голову как можно ему объяснить какой элемент первый, код ниже

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main container">

      <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Bootstrap Multi-Card Carousel</h1>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner carousel-inner-two row w-100 mx-auto">
          <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-two col-md-4 active">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-two col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-two col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-two col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-two col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f49b41/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-two col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f4f141/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-two col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/8e41f4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

css

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* show 3 items */
  .carousel-inner-two .active,
  .carousel-inner-two .active+.carousel-item-two,
  .carousel-inner-two .active+.carousel-item-two+.carousel-item-two {
    display: block;
  }
  .carousel-inner-two .carousel-item-two.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
  .carousel-inner-two .carousel-item-two.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item-two,
  .carousel-inner-two .carousel-item-two.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item-two+.carousel-item-two {
    transition: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner-two .carousel-item-next,
  .carousel-inner-two .carousel-item-prev {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner-two .active.carousel-item-two+.carousel-item-two+.carousel-item-two+.carousel-item-two {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -33.3333%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* left or forward direction 
  *Если изменить в первой строке .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left на .carousel-item-two-next.carousel-item-left, то первый слайдер начнет работать правильно, но второй нет
  */
  .active.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
  .carousel-inner-two .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* right or prev direction */
  .active.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item-two,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item-two+.carousel-item-two,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item-two+.carousel-item-two+.carousel-item-two {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

JS

```
$("#myCarousel").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
  var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var idx = $e.index();
  var itemsPerSlide = 3;
  var totalItems = $(".carousel-item-two").length;

  if (idx >= totalItems - (itemsPerSlide - 1)) {
    var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
    for (var i = 0; i < it; i++) {
      // append slides to end
      if (e.direction == "left") {
        $(".carousel-item-two")
          .eq(i)
          .appendTo(".carousel-inner-two");
      } else {
        $(".carousel-item-two")
          .eq(0)
          .appendTo(".carousel-inner-two");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Значит пишу код

```
     <?php foreach ($recomendet_product as $sliderItem): ?>
      <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-two col-md-4 
       <?php if (Что-то должно произойти) echo 'active';?>">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Отображается по 3 плитки, одна из них с классом active

Comment: До цикла объявить переменную, например $i = 1. В самом цикле увеличивать ее на 1 и проверять. Если $i == 1 значит это первый элемент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все очень просто.

```
$i = 0;
foreach { 
  $i++;
  if ($i == 1) { 
    echo “<div class=‘class active’>”;
  }else{
    echo “<div class=‘class’>”;
  }
}
```